# C - invalid branch to/from OpenMP structured block

Tags: c, multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp

I have a code in c that counts the numbers of occurrences of specific words but I want to do it with openmp.

Which word is a char and its defined in main()

When I try to compile it I get the following error:

> In function ‘wordCount’: error: invalid branch to/from OpenMP structured block

I tried to search this same error, but I'm not being able to fix it, I'm very newbie in openmp and especially in c.

Here's the whole code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <sys/time.h>
    #include <omp.h>
    
    struct timeval t1, t2;
    
    void execTime(){
      double t_total = (t2.tv_sec - t1.tv_sec) + ((t2.tv_usec - t1.tv_usec)/1000000.0);
      printf("\n");
      printf("\n");
      printf("Total Time = %f\n", t_total);
      printf("\n");
    }
    
    int wordCount(char* file_path, char* word){
        FILE *fp;
        int count = 0;
        int ch, len;
    
        if(NULL==(fp=fopen(file_path, "r")))
            return -1;
        len = strlen(word);
        for(;;){
            int i;
            if(EOF==(ch=fgetc(fp))) break;
            if((char)ch != *word) continue;
            
           omp_set_num_threads(4);
    
           #pragma omp parallel for  
            for(i=1;i < len;++i){
                if(EOF==(ch = fgetc(fp))) 
                    goto end;
                if((char)ch != word[i]){
                    fseek(fp, 1-i, SEEK_CUR);
                    goto next;
                }
            }
            ++count;
            next: ;
        }
        end:
            fclose(fp);
            return count;
    }
    
    int main()
    {
        char word1[] = "hello";
        char word2[] = "libero";
        char word3[] = "egestas";
        char word4[] = "vestibulum";
    
        int wordcount1 = 0;
        int wordcount2 = 0;
        int wordcount3 = 0;
        int wordcount4 = 0;
    
        gettimeofday(&t1, NULL);
      
        wordcount1 = wordCount("file.txt", word1);
        wordcount2 = wordCount("file.txt", word2);
        wordcount3 = wordCount("file.txt", word3);
        wordcount4 = wordCount("file.txt", word4);
        gettimeofday(&t2, NULL);
    
        printf("Word hello occurs %d times\n",wordcount1);
        printf("Word libero occurs %d times\n",wordcount2);
        printf("Word egestas occurs %d times\n",wordcount3);
        printf("Word vestibulum occurs %d times\n",wordcount4);
        execTime();
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have in OpenMP goto statement inside a parallel for:

```
   #pragma omp parallel for  
    for(i=1;i < len;++i){
        if(EOF==(ch = fgetc(fp))) 
            goto end; // <-- the problem
        if((char)ch != word[i]){
            fseek(fp, 1-i, SEEK_CUR);
            goto next; // <-- the problem
        }
    }
```

And the same applies to the `break` statement, from the OpenMP 5.1 standard one can read:

> final-loop-body must not contain any break statement that would cause
> the termination of the innermost loop.

You can try to have a look the [OpenMP cancellation point](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpsu102.html) feature:

> **Summary**
>
> The cancellation point construct introduces a user-defined
> cancellation point at which implicit or explicit tasks check if
> cancellation of the innermost enclosing region of the type specified
> has been activated. The cancellation point construct is a stand-alone
> directive.

---

In your case, however, even if the goto was not an issue your code is not efficiently parallelizable as it is. For instance, the [fgetc](https://linux.die.net/man/3/explain_fgets)

> Note: This function is not thread safe, because it shares a return
> buffer across all threads, and many other functions in this library.
> const char *explain_errno_fgets(int errnum, char *data, int data_size,
> FILE *fp);

Is not thread safe, which mean that you would have to ensure [mutual exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusion) on its accesses, which would make your code basically sequential anyway. Typically is not recommended to read the same file in parallel anyway.